# Is $M_n$($\mathbf{C})$ spanned by {$AB-BA$ where A,B in $M_n$($\mathbf{C})$}?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that span of  {$AB-BA$ where A,B in $M_n$($\mathbf{R})$} is $n^2$ -1. But what happens if entries are from $\mathbf{C}$? Is $M_n$($\mathbf{C})$ spanned by {$AB-BA$ where A,B in $M_n$($\mathbf{C})$}, with base field $\mathbf{C}$ ?

Comment: Same idea should work. Commutators have trace zero

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the field.

For convenience, we use the standard notation $[A , B] := AB - BA$.

Let $F$ be any field, and denote by $M_n(F)$ the $F$-algebra of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $F$. Then the trace $\text{tr}: M_n(F) \to F$ is surjective linear map, and hence its kernel has dimension $n^2 - 1$. We claim that the kernel is equal to $W := \text{span}\{ [A , B] \mid A , B \in M_n(F) \}$. It follows from linearity of the trace and the fact that $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$ that $W \subseteq \ker(\text{tr})$. To show the reverse containment, note that

$$[E_{ij} , E_{k \ell}] = \delta_{jk} E_{i \ell} - \delta_{\ell i} E_{k j}$$

where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column and $0$'s everywhere else.

- Therefore for any $i \neq j$, we have that $[E_{i 1} , E_{1 j}] = \delta_{1 1} E_{i j} - \delta_{i j} E_{1 1} = E_{i j}$.
- Furthermore, for any $1 \leq i < n$, we have that $[E_{i \  i + 1} , E_{i + 1 \ i}] = \delta_{i + 1 \ i + 1} E_{ii} - \delta_{i i} E_{i + 1 \ i + 1}  = E_{i i} - E_{i + 1 \ i + 1}$.

Hence $\{ E_{i j} \mid i \neq j \} \cup \{ E_{i \ i + 1} \mid 1 \leq i < n \} \subseteq W$. However the former is a linearly independent set containing $n^2 - 1$ elements, so $\dim W \geq n^2  - 1$. Since we already showed that $\ker(\text{tr})$ has dimension $n^2 - 1$ and contains $W$, it follows that $W = \ker(\text{tr})$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

No, $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is NOT spanned by $\{AB-BA|A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\}$.

$\mathbb{I}_{n\times n}\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and $Tr(\mathbb{I}_{n\times n})=n$, $Tr$ denoting the trace. $Tr(AB-BA)=0$ for all $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and $Tr$ being a linear functional, it is zero on the span of $\{AB-BA|A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\}$ as well. So, $\mathbb{I}_{n\times n}\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ does not lie in the linear span of $\{AB-BA|A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\}$.