# How to prove Character space of $M_n$(C) is empty by following question?

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Prove that Mn(C) is spanned by {AB−BA : A, B ∈ Mn(C)}. Deduce that Ω
(
Mn(C)
) is empty, ie character space/Spectrum is empty.

Comment: By $C$, you mean $\mathbb{C}$, the complex numbers, right? Then the claim actually isn't true.

Comment: The fact that this isn't true, follows from this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4065066

Comment: here, by span, I mean w.r.t Banach Algebra. we have multiplication (of matrices) operation also. @UjanChakraborty

Comment: I see... then, of course, I take back my words... I have tried to provide a proof of the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question (independent from the first part): the characters here are $\star$-homomorphisms from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}$. The kernel of this homomorphism must be a two-sided ideal. $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has no nontrivial two-sided ideals, so the kernel can only be either the full algebra or zero. However, the range being at most one-dimensional, by rank nullity, kernel must have dimension at least $n^2-1$. So, the only choice is the zero homomorphism, which is not a character, which means, the character space is empty.

Regarding obtaining the second part from the first part: this follows directly from the definition of characters ($\star$-homomorphisms), since the range $\mathbb{C}$ is commutative.